# JS/jQuery dynamically create arrays for each BUTTON GROUP then store BUTTON DATA VALUE accordingly on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 button groups with multiple buttons each. I can add/remove buttons' data-value to/from a global array, but I need one array for each button grup. Cannot do that, I always end up with only 1 array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // create array (need 2 arrays, actually)
  var dataValueArr = [];

  // on button click
  $(".button-group button").click(function() {

    var dataValue = $(this).data("value");

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {

      $(this).removeClass("selected");

      // remove value from array
      var filteredValues = dataValueArr.filter(function(e) {
        return e !== dataValue;
      });
      dataValueArr = filteredValues;

    } else {

      $(this).addClass("selected");
      
      // add value to array
      dataValueArr.push(dataValue);
    }

    console.log(dataValueArr);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-group">
  <button data-value="1">1</button>
  <button data-value="2">2</button>
</div>

<div class="button-group">
  <button class="selected" data-value="A">A</button>
  <button data-value="B">B</button>
  <button data-value="C">C</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by create the array using `window[Arrayname] = []`, in the example below we get the index of the buttongroup and use that combines with a string to create the name for the array.

so if you add another button group you don't have to change the jquery.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // on button click
  $(".button-group button").click(function() {
    var btninx = $(this).closest(".button-group").index();
    if (!window["dataValueArr" + btninx]) window["dataValueArr" + btninx] = [];

    var dataValue = $(this).data("value");

    if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {

      $(this).removeClass("selected");

      // remove value from array
      var filteredValues = window["dataValueArr" + btninx].filter(function(e) {
        return e !== dataValue;
      });
      window["dataValueArr" + btninx] = filteredValues;

    } else {

      $(this).addClass("selected");

      // add value to array
      window["dataValueArr" + btninx].push(dataValue);
    }

    console.log(window["dataValueArr" + btninx]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-group">
  <button data-value="1">1</button>
  <button data-value="2">2</button>
</div>

<div class="button-group">
  <button class="selected" data-value="A">A</button>
  <button data-value="B">B</button>
  <button data-value="C">C</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach is what I needed.

Comment: It appears that if you have the `".button-group"` wrapped inside other parents of their own for example `"section"`, this code stops working.

Comment: To solve this limitation, I replaced `index()` with a different variable that clearly identifies the `".button-group"`.